# I can't see my LinearLayout, why?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

My Code:

```
LinearLayout rb = new LinearLayout(this);
int idy = getResources().getIdentifier("rb"+i, "Ressourcen_Reihe1", getPackageName());
rb.setBackground(normalBox);
rb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
rb.addView(imgBtnItem);
```

I can't see the LinearLayout.
What's my mistake?

Comment: Where is the code where you add rb to a ViewGroup parent?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided code, rb has not been made part of a live view hierarchy.  You'll need to add it to a ViewGroup associated with the layout for your fragment/activity somewhere for it to show up.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added any `LayoutParams` to the View. Therefore, it takes up no space.

Also, you haven't shown `rb` being added to a parent layout.